# Is there anyway to increase the product per row and decrease the size of the image of each product?

Tags: bigcartel

I want to make the pictures of the product smaller. I also want to add another product per each row so it is 4 products instead of 3 products per row.

My Website:
http://www.notsomefantasy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set 4 products per row on the desktop view for this particular theme by adding the following piece of code to the bottom of Customize Design > Advanced > CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .product-card {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .product-link .product-image {
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```